# Sails.js / Waterline: findOne() vs find()

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

TestController.js:

```
module.exports = {
    test: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({}, function(err, found) {
      console.log(found);
      return res.send(found);
    })
  }
};
```

The `User` model contains one single entry. When this controller runs, the result that's being sent is `null` or `undefined`.
However, if `User.findOne({})` is replaced with `User.find({})`, suddenly the `found` variable is an array which includes the single entry:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Walter Jr",
    "createdAt": "2014-11-16T09:59:48.232Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-11-16T09:59:48.232Z",
    "id": "5468759459f51a307b47bffd"
  }
]
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't think this one through but for the benefit of everyone who's googling, here's what's up:

Once you dig into the `err`, you'll find:

```
{
  "error": "E_UNKNOWN",
  "status": 500,
  "summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
  "raw": {}
}
```

In other words, Waterline's `findOne` always requires some sort of a query to find one item; it won't automatically find first one on any list and return it, that's not specific enough for findOne.